# Load vba to excel module from a url

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if it's possible to load or link vba code to the module in excel? 
( like in JavaScript src = "script.js")

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you mean use a variable from the 'ThisWorkbook' code or one module to another module?

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis I am referring to, lets say I have a .BAS file uploaded on a server. Can I link that module in my workbook and call macros from that?

Answer (score 0):

To call a module:

```
Sub main()
    Call Macro
End Sub
```

Or you do something like this:

```
Sub main()
    moduleName.subName
End Sub
```